# .Net, convert "8.33333333329E-2" to percents

Tags: types

I'm reading excel and there's cell that represents total cost of budget in percents.

In excel it looks like `8%`, but once i read it, i get string `8.33333333329E-2`.

Got confused a bit.

What would be correct data type and parsing technique to use and avoid losing data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like `((int)Math.Round(value*100)).ToString() + "%";`.

Comment: Arrggghhhhhh, please use the format specifier for strings, iow `value.ToString("P0")`. A lot shorter and less error-prone.

Comment: @leppi Are you saying you'd prefer to see `((int)Math.Round(value*100)).ToString("P0") + "%";`?

Comment: A good thing about Math.Round is that you control how it's rounded; for example, you can specify whether you want 0.077 to be displayed as 7% or as 8%.

Comment: @ChrisW: No, just `value.ToString("P0")`, it's all that is needed.

Comment: @ChrisW: If you use round like that, it is wrong. You have functions like floor, ceiling, truncate, etc for those. They also behave correctly on negative numbers.

Comment: `value` is string, i can't just multiple it with 100. Can't convert it to decimal cause of trailing `E-2`.

Comment: @Arnis L.: `double.Parse` should have no issue parsing that.

Comment: Emm. It almost works. Period makes problems. `8.333...` fails, `8,333` works. What format provider it needs? Or anything else?

Comment: @Arnis L. - My guess would be `NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo`

Comment: I guess it's fine now. Know how to parse it and know how to display it. Thank You ChrisW and leppie.

Answer (score 2):

You probably have the excel cell formatting set to 0 decimal digits, and hence you see the wrong value, while 0.0833333333 is the actual value.

If you do want it as 0.08 (or 8%), round the value in excel.

Comment: Indeed. For background, percentages in Excel are actually floating point numbers, where 1.0 represents 100%, i.e. if you stick 0.25 in a cell in Excel and format it as a percentage, it'll display as "25%". This is why your 8.333E-2, roughly 0.08, displays at 8%, when formatted as a percentage with no decimal places.

Comment: No can do. Excel should not be touched at all.

Comment: @leppie question is - how to work with it at .Net side now how it looks in excel. :)

Comment: @Arnis L.: Convert it to string or round it, like the above answer, if that is what your really want to do.

Comment: @leppie it is string already. I want to save it in another data type that would represent percentage more naturally.